# After move the GridSplitter, the layout don't work correctly

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol, gridsplitter

My purpose is that: double-click the `TabItem` named "Tab" in the `TabControl`, then the `TabControl` will be folded, another double-click lead to unfolded. 
But after I move the `GridSplitter` and double-click the "Tab" to be folded, it don't work correctly that the the height of the column the `TabControl` in isn't equal to the height of the `TabControl`, in other word, **`GridSplitter` don't follow the "TabControl"**.

[image]

**.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication7.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="20"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                <Label>
                    Nothing
                </Label>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" 
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                      VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                      Height="6" />
        <TabControl Grid.Row="2" 
                    TabStripPlacement="Bottom" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <TabItem Header="Tab" 
                     MouseDoubleClick="TabItemDoubleCilck">
                <!--ListView-->
                <ListView Grid.Row="1"
                          xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="AA " 
                                        Width="100"
                                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding [0]}" />
                            <GridViewColumn Header="BB" 
                                        Width="100"
                                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding [1]}" />
                            <GridViewColumn Header="CC" 
                                        Width="100"
                                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding [2]}" />
                            <GridViewColumn Header="DD" 
                                        Width="100"
                                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding [3]}" />
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                    <ListViewItem>
                        <x:Array Type="sys:String" >
                            <sys:String>2000/01/01</sys:String>
                            <sys:String>2000/01/01</sys:String>
                            <sys:String>2000/01/01</sys:String>
                            <sys:String>2000/01/01</sys:String>
                        </x:Array>
                    </ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem>
                        <x:Array Type="sys:String" >
                            <sys:String>2000/01/01</sys:String>
                            <sys:String>2000/01/01</sys:String>
                            <sys:String>2000/01/01</sys:String>
                            <sys:String>2000/01/01</sys:String>
                        </x:Array>
                    </ListViewItem>
                </ListView>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication7
{
    /// <summary>
    /// MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        const double dBottomTabMinHeight = 20.0;

        private bool isBottomTabUnfold;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            isBottomTabUnfold = true;
        }

        private void TabItemDoubleCilck(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            TabItem tabItm = sender as TabItem;
            if (isBottomTabUnfold)
            {
                ((FrameworkElement)tabItm.Parent).Height = dBottomTabMinHeight;
            }
            else
            {
                ((FrameworkElement)tabItm.Parent).Height = Double.NaN;

            }
            isBottomTabUnfold = !isBottomTabUnfold;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please check the edited answer of mine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, hope this is what you expected

```
    private void TabItemDoubleCilck(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        TabItem tabItm = sender as TabItem;
        if (isBottomTabUnfold)
        {
            ((FrameworkElement)tabItm.Parent).Height = dBottomTabMinHeight;
            ((FrameworkElement)tabItm.Parent).VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
        }
        else
        {
            ((FrameworkElement)tabItm.Parent).Height = Double.NaN;
            ((FrameworkElement)tabItm.Parent).VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
        }
        isBottomTabUnfold = !isBottomTabUnfold;
    }
```

edit:

like this then?

```
    private void TabItemDoubleCilck(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        TabItem tabItm = sender as TabItem;
        if (isBottomTabUnfold)
        {
            dUnfoldedHeight = ((FrameworkElement)tabItm.Parent).ActualHeight;
            ((FrameworkElement)tabItm.Parent).Height = dBottomTabMinHeight;
            rowTab.Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto);
        }
        else
        {
            ((FrameworkElement)tabItm.Parent).Height = double.NaN;
            rowTab.Height = new GridLength(dUnfoldedHeight);

        }
        isBottomTabUnfold = !isBottomTabUnfold;
    }
```

NB:

- rowTab is the name of the 3rd rowdefinition, dUnfoldedHeight is a private member to track the height of the unfolded tab before it's folded.
- you might find a weird behavior on dragging the splitter up when the tab is folded or when dragging the spliiter down until the tab is look like unfolded, to fix this you probably have to work with the DragDelta and DragCompleted event of the splitter to decide whether in the end the tab should be considered as folded or not

Comment: sorry, the 'GridSplitter' still stay the same. I just want it to follow the 'TabControl' up and down.